# Rails 3 assets pipeline js error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have all the javascript files under `app/assets/javascripts`

Some of the javascript files

- application.js
- effect.js
- rails.js
- prototype.js
- scriptaculous.js

When pre compiling assets  `rake assets:precompile`  it creating `application.js` in public/assets

But the application.js file included only the content present in `app/assets/javascript/application.js` ,not including other js file contents(efect,prototype).

If I add javascript files to  config.assets.precompile like this

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( rails.js menu.js )
```

this create separate js file for each in  `public/assets`

In my production.rb file

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)

config.serve_static_assets = true

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true
```

I need to combine all javascript files into singlefile.

I'm using prototype.

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `application.js` you have to include the files you want to combine adding this in the beggining:

```
//= require effect
//= require rails
//= require prototype
//= require scriptaculous
```

or if they are all in the same folder

```
//= require_tree .
```

Then in your application you must include tags only for application.js, not for each one.